# How to create different ComboBox ItemTemplate for dropdown

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

How to define custom template for ComboBox in my UWP App, for Dropdown I need a checkbox with label, but when user selects any option I just need to show label in comobox

I tried this but I didn't work:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbCountry"
                      Header="Country"
                      Margin="10,5"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Use only one template and check box visibility can be handled depending on whether it is selecteditem or not. You can use converter for that

Comment: I am new to UWP, some code demo will be helpful.

Comment: Ok. I ll add the sample in a while.

Comment: Did anyone found out any other way to doing this.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbState" DropDownClosed="cbState_DropDownClosed" DropDownOpened="cbState_DropDownOpened"  Margin="75,287,0,0" Width="169" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}"   >

                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" 
                                   Visibility="{Binding IsCheckBoxVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                            </CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding State_Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ComboBox>

   private void cbState_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
        {
            foreach (var item in (sender as ComboBox).Items)
            {
                (item as State).IsCheckBoxVisible = false;
            }
        }

        private void cbState_DropDownOpened(object sender, object e)
        {
            foreach(var item in (sender as ComboBox).Items)
            {
                (item as State).IsCheckBoxVisible = true;
            }
        }
```

Converter class

```
 public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var boolValue = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

            return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible) ? true : false;
            ;
        }
    }
```

Model class. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged to reflect changes in UI(checkbox visibility changes)

```
 public class State:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string State_Name { get; set; }
        public object State_Id { get; set; }
        bool isCheckBoxVisible;
        public bool IsCheckBoxVisible
        {
            get { return isCheckBoxVisible; }
            set
            {
                if (value != isCheckBoxVisible)
                {
                    isCheckBoxVisible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckBoxVisible");
                }
            }
        }
        public State(string name,object id,bool visibility=false)
        {
            State_Name = name;
            State_Id = id;
            IsCheckBoxVisible = false;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return State_Name;
        }
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            // the new Null-conditional Operators are thread-safe:
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

Comment: It works but I think it's better to bind the converter to the IsDropDownOpen property of the ComboBox.